# Grails 1.3.7 "is not a valid Grails plugin. No plugin.xml descriptor found!" error when trying to install plugins in Jenkins

Tags: grails, jenkins, grails-plugin

I'm facing these random errors even after having them installed via command "grails install-plugin plugin_name plugin_version". This is part of a Jenkins build where the code is first checked-out, then built with grails, then "prod war" as target.
Grails is able to find and install the plugins it needs, but still fails for different version of this plugin and I don't know where it is picking that versions from.

Here's a snippet of the error: https://gist.github.com/marianogg9/e208233042c721bdbd87

Here's my BuildConfig.groovy: https://gist.github.com/marianogg9/438dc35d4643affe6e19

Any help is greatly appreciated, I've run out of options here.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are defining `spring security core` jar dependency as plugin and that's why it can't be prosessed.

In your `BuildConfig.groovy` move it from the `plugins {}` to `dependencies {}`

```
grails.project.dependency.resolution = {

    ...

    plugins {
        compile ":burning-image:0.5.0"
        compile ":email-confirmation:1.0.5"
        compile ":mail:1.0"
        runtime ":hibernate:$grailsVersion"
        runtime ":jquery:1.7.1"
    }

    dependencies {
        ...
        compile ":spring-security-core:1.2.7.2"
    }
}
```

Comment: @marianogg9 did this work for you? i'm trying to update a really old grails 1.3.7 and am running into this issue